# Failed to build for blackberry 10 v 10.2 with worklight 6.1

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

Could not deploy to bb 10.2 and got a message saying "[ERROR]Error initializing Cordova: Extension Device not found".
It is a brand new app created by using create new worklight project.

Tried many times. No idea what is wrong. Please help.

I tried to build my hybrid app for bb10. I got warning in console saying

```
[WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: Battery
[WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: Camera
[WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: com.blackberry.utils
[WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: org.apache.cordova.blackberry10.pimlib
[WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: Contacts
[WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: Device
```

I actually got warnings for most feature i got.

In my config.xml file, i got:

```
<!-- Start: Features -->
<!-- Cordova API -->
<feature id="Battery" name="Battery" value="Battery"/>
<feature id="Camera" name="Camera" value="Camera"/>
<feature id="com.blackberry.utils" name="com.blackberry.utils" value="com.blackberry.utils"/>
<feature id="org.apache.cordova.blackberry10.pimlib" name="org.apache.cordova.blackberry10.pimlib"
         value="org.apache.cordova.blackberry10.pimlib"/>
<feature id="Contacts" name="Contacts" value="Contacts"/>
<feature id="Device" name="Device" value="Device"/>
```

I do not know why I got those warning. I asked people and it seems to be normal to get above messages. However, when I launch the bb10 app, I got a javascript alert message saying: "[ERROR]Error initializing Cordova: Extension Device not found".

I am building the project using worklight 6.1.
My blackberry version is 10.2.
Webworks SDK is the latest 1 point something from website.
Steps to build exactly:

1. Inside worklight, I chose to build for bb10 environment. Inside app folder/blackberry10 -> Run As -> Build for Blackberry 10 Environment.
2. Then in the console, I go the bb10 sdk: use bbwp  -o
3. Then in the console, I sign the bar file.
4. Then I deploy the file to device using BB10 App Manager.

Anyone knows what might be wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/worklight_blackberry10_project_with_webworks_sdk_2_0?lang=en

Comment: @IdanAdar how about Webworks SDK 1. something?

Comment: Oh, in that case I'm not sure.

Comment: Actually I figure it out. It complains that for some qnx extension is missing inside webworks ext folder. I need manually copy everything inside native/www/qnx-ext files to webworks framework/ext folder and then it would solve the problem.

Comment: pleas write this as an answer or remove the question...

Answer (score 0):

The user will not provide his answer as the answer...

Here is a quote:

> Actually I figure it out. It complains that for some qnx extension is
>   missing inside webworks ext folder. I need manually copy everything
>   inside native/www/qnx-ext files to webworks framework/ext folder and
>   then it would solve the problem.